# Why is json_populate_record() not recognizing row type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6, node-postgres

I have 2 tables `type` and `name`. I am trying to insert into these with json_populate_record() through a function. Receiving the following error:

```
first argument of json_populate_record must be a row type
```

Table `type` is created using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "type" (
  "id"    TEXT NOT NULL,
  "value" TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CHECK ("id"<>'' AND "value"<>'')
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "idx_type_value"
ON "type" ("value");


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "type_insertone" (
  IN _a JSON
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "type" SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"type", _a);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Table `name` is created using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "name" (
  "id"    TEXT NOT NULL,
  "value" TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  CHECK ("id"<>'' AND "value"<>'')
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "idx_name_value"
ON "name" ("value");


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "name_insertone" (
  IN _a JSON
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "name" SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"name", _a);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When is call `type_insertone()` with `{id: 'x', 'value': 'x'}`, it works.
But when i do the same with `name_insertone()` it doesnt work!

I was thinking if it could be possible that the function is created before the table is created, which could be causing it to not know the table `name`, but that i think is not the case.

I dont know what should i try here. I have also checked that `name` is not a reserved keyword and so is `type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"name" is a text type [and a key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html look at the bottom, so when you cast to "name" you cast to name data type, not to your table rowtype...

eg:

```
t=# alter table name rename to name1;
ALTER TABLE
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "name_insertone" (
  IN _a JSON
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO "name1" SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"name1", _a);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select name_insertone('{"id": "x", "value": "x"}');
 name_insertone
----------------

(1 row)
```

and yet:

```
t=# create table text(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"text", '{}')
t-# ;
ERROR:  first argument of json_populate_record must be a row type
t=# create table char(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::"char", '{}');
ERROR:  first argument of json_populate_record must be a row type
```

Comment: But `"name"` should be a different thing then `name`?

Comment: not sure here. I would just avoid using name as name, especially when you want to use it as rowtype

Comment: franky saying my knowledge is very limited here, but if you try creating tables with text, char, varchar as names you meet same `ERROR:  first argument of json_populate_record must be a row type` trying to cast null to it as rowtype. Maybe Laurenz will pass by and explain why it happens?..

Comment: sure, no worries - interesting what is the order of candidates for explicit cast with same name, I guess from pg_cast would go first anyway, but could not find it in docs

Comment: i think you are suggesting some method that it could still work, but i didnt understand. when i tried this i assumed that `name` must not be a keyword as it was listed in the list as a non-reserved keyword. i wouldnt even have searched this, because i assumed by default a double-quote means an identifier, and even if such a keyword existed it didnt matter, but in this case it did.